# What is the phrase for 'essential spark' or 'unifying vision' that unique pieces of writing have that bring people together around a cause?

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

Some pieces of writing delight people with a vision that causes them to act together with purpose. They have some essential quality. Adam Smith using the idea of the Guiding Hand of the Market. Or the songs of John Lennon offering a new future. Or the speeches Martin Luther King, including his ‘I have a dream’ speech. Or the preamble to the United States Constitution, “We the people.” Or even the writings of John Calvin and Thomas Hobbes. These contained some vital essence or distinctive spark that lead people to rally around them.

Others aim for this, and miss the mark entirely. Example of this would be drab Corporate Mission statements of the late 90s, done more for conformance with the crowd than gathering people around an idea: “To ensure our employees to deliver more for this company’s shareholders and customers.”

My question is:  **What is the phrase for 'essential spark' or 'unifying vision' that unique pieces of writing have that bring people together around a cause?**

Comment: This is just pro-Communist, anti-capitalist spam.

Comment: Whether one agrees with a philosophy or not does not preclude questions about it. However the question could explicitly say whether one should approach the subject approvingly or not: *polemic* might be neutral; *rabble-rousing* rather less so.

Comment: I’m sorry to have offended you, I’ll try another example to illustrate my point.

Comment: The question is valid and interesting whether composed with the original example of Marx or with the edited examples. Although having no respect for Marx, I am disappointed that the question should have been so vituperatively attacked and (I presume) downvoted because of a seemingly doctrinaire reaction to his mention. I have upvoted accordingly. I use *disappointed* in the British manner of an understating euphemism.

Comment: Perhaps clarifying might be helpful -- vision is a different thing than spark (nugget). I'm just not sure that an idea really can generate any sort of widespread acceptance or adherence by itself. That's usually the domain of well-meaning friends at least, or entire PR departments.

Comment: Where does the quoted sentence “To ensure our employees to deliver more for this company’s shareholders and customers” come from? This is not standard English, and suggests an absence of an actual example of corporation’s mission statement done for “conformance with the crowd.”

Comment: Thanks @Xanne - The bad ones aren't shared externally, ie they are internal.  To share one would be a breach of intellectual property and company secrecy (ie get you fired). This is a hypothetical example of a particularly uninspiring one. I agree it is not standard English - and that is an essential characteristic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “unifying vision” that brings people together around a cause can be called a *rallying cry*:

> *A **rallying cry** or **rallying call** is something such as a word or phrase, an event, or a belief which encourages people to unite and
> to act in support of a particular group or idea.*
>   <sub>Source:
> [Collins—*rallying
> cry*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/rallying-cry)</sub>

Examples:

> *In the iconic speech Dr. King publicly declared, “We shall overcome” – a phrase that became a rallying cry for the civil rights
> movement.*
>   <sub>Source: [The University of Memphis—”Original
> Handwritten Martin Luther King Jr. Speech to be
> Displayed . . .”](https://www.memphis.edu/mediaroom/releases/2018/march18/mlkspeech.php)</sub>

> *Recorded in a Montreal hotel room during his and Yoko Ono’s honeymoon, John Lennon’s “Give Peace a Chance” was a rallying cry—or
> as he described it, a commercial for peace.*
>  <sub>Source: [Apple
> Music—”Give Peace a
> Chance”](https://music.apple.com/us/playlist/give-peace-a-chance/pl.5e75bc84d1f6493fba5e77f617b290be)</sub>

If you’re looking for “essential qualities” shared by these writings, try:

> *inspirational*—giving you the enthusiasm to do or create
> something
>  <sub>Source:
> [MacMillan—*inspirational*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/inspirational)</sub>

> *motivational*—designed to promote the desire or willingness to do or
> achieve something.
>  <sub>Source:
> [Lexico—*motivational*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/motivational)</sub>

Examples:

> *John Lennon’s inspirational song . . .*

> *Martin Luther King Jr.’s motivational speech . . .*

Antonyms for *inspirational* and *motivational* include *dull* and *unaffecting* (like your 90s corporate mission statement, perhaps).

.

PS: I might label Adam Smith’s concepts (along with those of Calvin and Hobbes) as *visionary* or *influential* or *ideological* rather than *inspiring*:

> ? *Smith’s “invisible hand” concept makes us want to go shopping!*